# Just Making Sure

Tags: java, variables, netbeans, trace

I am new to JAVA and I have to use paper and a pencil to create a variable trace for the following code, tracing the values of `num1, num2, i, and any output`. This is the code I have to trace:

```
int num1 = 0;        
int num2 = 0:       

for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){        
          num1 = i * i;    
          num2 += num1;     
          System.out.println(num1 + " ");        
}      
System.out.println(num2);
```

This is my first trace I have no idea what the format is. This is what I have done so far:

```
Variable i  Variable num1   Variable num2   Output    
0                0              0              0    
1                1              1              1      
2                4              4              5    
3                9              9              14    
4               16              16             30    
5            False Condition    30
```

(1) When `i=0` num1 is also 0 because `num1 = i * i;`
And to find num2 we do `num2 += num1;` which also makes it 0.
(2) When `i=1` num1 is also 1 because `num1 = i * i;`
And to find num2 we do `num2 += num1;` which also makes it 1.

And so on

For the output, when it adds `(num2+=num1)` the value of num2 remains. So, it adds num1 value with the previous output. So, even though num2 and output are the same the value is different but they both display 30 at the end and when you add all values of num2 it adds up to 30. So, it would display `0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 30.`

I just want to make sure that I have done it right and if I haven't can you please suggest on how I can improve it? Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Last line: Just want to make sure I did it correctly and if I didn't can you suggest improvements? First time doing it, dont know the format

Comment: You haven't done it right, and you could know it by printing the value of i, num1 and num2 at each iteration.

Comment: `num2 += num1` behaves differently then you have traced. It should be `0, 1, 5, 14, 30`.

Comment: What do you mean? What part have I not done right?

Comment: **you could know it by printing the value of i, num1 and num2 at each iteration**. Do it, and try figuring it out by yourself. Learn what += means. Given that you already print num1 at each iteration, the output and the num1 column should contain the same value.

Comment: I ran it and this was the output it gave me :0,1,4,9,16,30

Comment: Oh, so you are saying that output column should be 0,1,4,9,16,30 as well? or should they both be completely different?

Comment: So that already proves that your output column is wrong, since it contains 0, 1, 5, 14, 30. Now also print i and num2, to find out what their value is.

Comment: I thought i and num2 were already correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct table is

```
num1    num2    i       output
0       0       0       0
1       1       1       1
4       5       2       4
9       14      3       9
16      30      4       16
                5       30
```

Comment: oh so I had to flip num2 and output around

Comment: I don't think you understood what num2+=num1 meant

Comment: num2+=num1; translates to num2=num2+num1;